# How do I stop getting notifications for a chat event?

Tags: support, chat, notifications, events

For example, I registered for "Happy Hour" on Meta Stack Overflow chat; now every week I get a notification about it. I am most of time unable to follow it and want to de-register from getting these notifications. I cannot seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Wait, what? What is a "Happy Hour" notification? What is "Happy Hour?" I don't think this even exists....

Comment: @Doorknob - He is talking about Chat events

Comment: It says a scheduled chat is about to start, with the link for Happy Hour as "http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?noredirect=1" and there doesn't seem to be a way for not getting this

Comment: @hims OH that makes sense. :P I was confused at first

Comment: Does Happy Hour come with free booze?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use the <kbd>cancel your registration</kbd> button on the event page; the notification should be linking you to it.

For example, on the [Happy Hour event page](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/89/tavern-on-the-meta?tab=schedule):

[image: It's at the end of the event info, just above the registration list.]